# how to remove slidetoggle hidden div when window width reaches certain size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this irritating problem when I toggle a menu in smartphone view the menu stays hidden when resized to desktop view.

So when the window reaches width of about 905px I want to remove the effect of the toggle and show the navigation from hidden to shown.

I am not sure how to fix this as I've no knowledge of JQuery

Here is my code

```
<div id="menu">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
                    <li class="remove-margin"><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
                </ul>       
            </nav>
        </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).resize(function(){
    if ($(window).width() >= 905){  

    }   
})
$("#menu").addClass("responsive").before('<div id="three-lines"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></div>');
$("#three-lines").click(function(){
$("#menu").slideToggle('fast');
})
</script>
```

Comment: in `if` condition put `$("#menu").slideDown('fast');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just show the element when the condition is reached.

```js
$(function() {



  $("#menu").addClass("responsive")
            .before('<div id="three-lines"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></div>');
 
  $("#three-lines").click(function() {
    $("#menu").slideToggle('fast');
  })


  addEventListener("resize", function() {
    if (innerWidth >= 905) {
      $("#menu").show();
    }
  })

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">About us</a>
      </li>
      <li class="remove-margin"><a href="#">Contact us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

Using media queries

```
@media screen and (min-width: 905px) {
    #menu{
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Comment: Run above code snippet, click on menu, then click on full page option, so that width would be >=905, and see the menu appearing

Comment: @Thank you it works but that sliding effect is there a way of just making the nav appear without it?

Comment: yes.. use `show()` instead of  `slideDown()`.. updated the answer

Comment: Thanks it works, in terms of good practices is this a good way of fixing the problem, approaching it or there could be another simpler way through css and media-queries?

Comment: You are correct, best practise would be going with media queries.